# why are empty strings converted to null passing to the constructor of the domain object in Grails 2.4.0?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock, data-conversion

I'm new to Groovy and Grails. The Spock test for the domain object to test persist fails due to the empty string being converted to null. Here is the code.
The domain object,

```
class Todo {

    String name
    Date createdDate
    String priority
    String status

    static constraints = {
        priority blank: true
    }

}
```

The Spock specification,

```
@TestFor(Todo)
class TodoSpec extends Specification {

    void "test persist"() {
        when:
        new Todo(name: 't1', createdDate: new Date(), priority: "1", status: 'ok').save()
        new Todo(name: 't2', createdDate: new Date(), priority: '', status: 'ok').save()

        then:
        Todo.list().size() == 2
    }

}
```

The result of `grails test-app` is

```
Todo.list().size() == 2
     |      |      |
     |      1      false
     [collab.todo.Todo : 1]
        at collab.todo.TodoSpec.test persist(TodoSpec.groovy:18)
```

I found the empty string `''` in the line `new Todo(name: 't2', createdDate: new Date(), priority: '', status: 'ok')` is converted to `null` by debugging. After google a while, I see there is a feature in Grails converting the empty strings from the web form to null to persist, which can be disabled by a configuration `grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false` in the Config.groovy. But I don't think this is the case for Spock UT. I've tried but it doesn't work as I thought.

I was wondering why the empty string is converted to null as a parameter passing to the constructor? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a little hinky right now, but can be made to work pretty easily.  The following test passes with Grails 2.3.9...

A domain class:

```
// grails-app/domain/com/demo/Person.groovy
package com.demo

class Person {
    String title
}
```

Config.groovy:

```
// grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false

// ...
```

A unit test:

```
// test/unit/com/demo/PersonSpec.groovy
package com.demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(Person)
@TestMixin(grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin)
class PersonSpec extends Specification {

    void "test empty string conversion"() {
        when:
        def p = new Person(title: '')

        then:
        p.title == ''
    }
}
```

The key is applying the ContollerUnitTestMixin to the test case, even though it isn't really testing a controller.  See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11136.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, the test passes after add `@TestMixin(grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin)`.

Comment: this just solved a huge problem for me, not too impressed with grails on this though, so much config and weird default behavior on this! anyway thanks!!

Comment: @soheildb "so much config and weird default behavior on this" - If you have recommendations for better default behavior, please file a request at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of empty strings to null is a feature of Grails databinding, so this will happen wherever databinding is used. One such place is when calling the constructor of a domain class with a map argument. If you don't want the string to be converted to null, try this:

```
new Todo().priority = ''
```